# CSS nth selection

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I have 4 paragraphs `<p>`. I need to select every paragraphs except leaving the first two paragraphs on this structure:

```
<div class="right">
  <a></a>
  <p>heading</p>
  <p></p>
  <p style="margin-bottom:6.0pt;vertical-align:baseline;">
    <span style="color:#2F2F2F ;">hi....Each day the world meets your expectations. It's no secret that your perspective shapes your experience.
    What's remarkable, however, is how belief builds awareness; and how with every insight, doors open, new futures unfold 
    and once-only-dreamed-of possibilities become everyday realities.</span>
  </p>
  <p style="margin-bottom:6.0pt;vertical-align:baseline;">
    <span style="color:#2F2F2F ;">Each day the world meets your expectations. It's no secret that your perspective shapes your experience.
    What's remarkable, however, is how belief builds awareness; and how with every insight, doors open, new futures unfold 
    and once-only-dreamed-of possibilities become everyday realities.</span>
  </p>

  <p style="margin-bottom:6.0pt;vertical-align:baseline;">
    <span style="color:#2F2F2F ;">Each day the world meets your expectations. It's no secret that your perspective shapes your experience.
    What's remarkable, however, is how belief builds awareness; and how with every insight, doors open, new futures unfold 
    and once-only-dreamed-of possibilities become everyday realities.</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

I wrote below css,

```
.right p:not(:nth-child(4)){
  background:yellow;
}
```

but it is selecting only first,third and fourth.

But we need only third and fourth only NOT first and second

how to achieve this?

Comment: `:nth-child(2n + 6)`

Comment: check https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/

Comment: Try `p:nth-child(n+3)`

Comment: Try `div > p ~ p ~ p { ... }`

Comment: @secelite that wouldn't work since based on the list is posted not all the childs are p tags

Comment: can you add the real markup of your elements ?

Comment: None of them worked

Comment: Added the real markup as requested

Comment: You can test it on : https://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/

Comment: [**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/a5bt43s5/)

Comment: By the way, why you have an empty `<p>` in markup?

Comment: need to select all , except first and second

Comment: @DaniP you are right. But as I was posting it, the markup was not provided.

Comment: yes extra markup creating issues, how it possible by taking out 3rd <P> as well , this works .right p:nth-of-type(n+3) {
  background:yellow;
}  but i need to eliminate thrid apart from 2 and 1 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [:nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) instead, try this:

```css
.right p:nth-of-type(n+3) {
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="right">
  <a href="#">I'm a link</a>
  <p>heading</p>
  <p>empty p</p>
  <p style="margin-bottom:6.0pt;vertical-align:baseline;">
    <span style="color:#2F2F2F ;">hi....Each day the world meets your expectations. It's no secret that your perspective shapes your experience.
What's remarkable, however, is how belief builds awareness; and how with every insight, doors open, new futures unfold 
and once-only-dreamed-of possibilities become everyday realities.</span>
  </p>
  <p style="margin-bottom:6.0pt;vertical-align:baseline;">
    <span style="color:#2F2F2F ;">Each day the world meets your expectations. It's no secret that your perspective shapes your experience.
What's remarkable, however, is how belief builds awareness; and how with every insight, doors open, new futures unfold 
and once-only-dreamed-of possibilities become everyday realities.</span>
  </p>

  <p style="margin-bottom:6.0pt;vertical-align:baseline;">
    <span style="color:#2F2F2F ;">Each day the world meets your expectations. It's no secret that your perspective shapes your experience.
What's remarkable, however, is how belief builds awareness; and how with every insight, doors open, new futures unfold 
and once-only-dreamed-of possibilities become everyday realities.</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: only leaving first item, i need to leave ,first and second

Comment: @SmartestVEGA it's leaving the first and second .... first is heading, second is empty p.... like your markup

Comment: off course @SmartestVEGA just add one to the selector like : `p:nth-of-type(n+4)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `:nth-child` or `:nth-type-of` pseudo-class to achieve the result:

```css
.right p:nth-of-type(n + 3) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="right">
<a href="">a link</a>
  <p>heading</p>
  <p>other p</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae nulla asperiores consequuntur quam numquam, fugit iusto, unde necessitatibus ullam nemo natus nobis iste delectus quae tenetur sunt qui odio blanditiis.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio commodi placeat voluptatem dolor, ullam quidem facere incidunt doloribus veritatis culpa nostrum magni tempora possimus consequatur ipsum aperiam ipsam, consectetur unde.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio commodi placeat voluptatem dolor, ullam quidem facere incidunt doloribus veritatis culpa nostrum magni tempora possimus consequatur ipsum aperiam ipsam, consectetur unde.</p>

</div>
```

[This Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ot2Lp2em/)